# How to print the IP and the Port separately with netstat?

Tags: linux, shell, netstat

I want to print the IP and the Port separately using `netstat` command,

I tried this:

```
netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}'
```

But It gives me that:

```
192.168.1.213:40405
```

I want something like that:

First the IP: `192.168.1.213`

and with another command the Port: `40405`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them as different commands, you could use sed to do it like:

```
netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/:.*//' # gives IP only
netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/.*://' # gives port only
```

Depending on how you're using it, you could store it in a bash variable and accomplish the same thing while access it like

```
both=$(netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}')
ip=${both%%:*}
port=${both##*:}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always pipe it into `cut`:

```
# Just the IP:
$ netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ":" -f1

# Just the port:
$ netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ":" -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using zsh shell and i am getting port in new line with the same command

```
netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}'
```

maybe try changing your profile preference